# DynamoDb re-processing records

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I just inherited some one else's code that uses a server-less lambda function to process records from DynamoDb. The original developer is using DynamoDb much like how RabbitMQ works; as a temporary staging area with some level of fault tolerance and a lambda function that will process them at a later date.

We currently have a way to delay message publication in RabbitMQ at my company, but this feature is missing on the AWS side of the fence.

I wrote some code in my serverless lambda function so that it checks a special property called `ProcessAfter` (UTC DateTime) and effectively skips processing any given DynamoDb record if the current UTC date/time is less than that specified by the `ProcessAfter`. However DynamoDb never sends me that record ever again. It appears that DynamoDb only ever allows a single attempt at processing a record (excluding the exception re-tries built in), so I'm stuck with my attempted solution to implementing a delay capability.

---

Is there anyway to replicate the delay functionality in DynamoDb, or in my lambda function so that messages are skipped, and then re-processed as often as necessary until the delay is over and the record is successfully processed?

Comment: Are you using DynamoDB streams? The architecture isn't clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are listening to dynamo_db streams. They work in a way if any event(insert, update etc which is being configured) happens for a record it will be sent to a listener for processing.

Now talking about your specific scenario, you need to have an SQS in place for processing a record later if you do not wish to process it after listening.

Better architecture I would advice is put an extra SQS and Lambda. The Lambda will listen the dynamo_db stream event, will compare processAfter with Date_Now to compute delay, add that delay as delay_seconds and send message to SQS.
Finally lambda listener will listen and process it after specified delay or 0 delay as required.